# Solving for an exponential variable that can not be issolated through factorisation.

Tags: proof-verification

$$(2^{x}-1)(2^{x}+4)(2^{x}-6)=0$$

My thinking:  At least one of the three terms given above should be equal to $0$.

But the middle term will never be equal to zero because $2^{x}$ can not be equal to a negative number.
Therefore $2^{x} -1=0$ thus $x=0$ and/or $2^{x}-6=0$ thus use log to solve for $x$.

Is my thinking correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: the second solution is $x=1+\log_23$

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).